# Orange border issue on textinputs on android

Tags: android, jquery, input, border

I know this is a well known issue, and I have tried a lot of solutions but it seems that there isn't a solution. I'm stuck trying to remove the orange border when a text input is touched on a samsung galaxy s2 android 4.0.4. I would like to know how it is done in the jquery mobile [demo page](http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.3.1/dist/demos/widgets/textinputs/).